# JQuery Tabs Content Help - 1.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to create some tabs on my website, here it goes:

```
<ul class="tabContainer">
       <!--Tabs Here -->
    </ul>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="tabContent">
        <div id="contentHolder">
            <!-- The content goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, i've seen the following used, but I was wondering if it was possible, instead of individual pages of content, to get individual divs instead:

so instead of:

```
var Tabs = {
    'Music' : 'pages/page1.html',
    'DVD' : 'pages/page2.html'.
}
```

use this instead:

```
var Tabs = {
    'Music' : 'div#fragment-1',
    'DVD' : 'div#fragment-2'.
}
```

Is this possible? Or is there another solution I can use to get the content somehow? I just want a simple ish solution where I can switch between 2 tabs of content, but for use in JQuery 1.4 only?

Hope you can help,

Snakespan

Comment: Sure, the code is from - http://tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sweet-tabs-jquery-ajax-css/ (a tutorial that has tabs for Jquery 1.4, which is what I have to create the website on).

Comment: Check the answer I have posted....

Comment: why not use Jquery UI, it has a function for tabs and alot more. http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like the following:

JS

```
$(function(){

function contentSwitcher(settings){
    var settings = {
       contentClass : '.content',
       navigationId : '#navigation'
    };

    //Hide all of the content except the first one on the nav
    $(settings.contentClass).not(':first').hide();
    $(settings.navigationId).find('li:first').addClass('active');

    //onClick set the active state, 
    //hide the content panels and show the correct one
    $(settings.navigationId).find('a').click(function(e){
        var contentToShow = $(this).attr('href');
        contentToShow = $(contentToShow);

        //dissable normal link behaviour
        e.preventDefault();

        //set the proper active class for active state css
        $(settings.navigationId).find('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');

        //hide the old content and show the new
        $(settings.contentClass).hide();
        contentToShow.show();
    });
}
contentSwitcher();
});
```

html

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul class="tabbedContent">
<li><a href="#page1">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2">link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#page3">link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#page4">link 4</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#page5">link 5</a></li>                                
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="page1" class="content">

</div>               
<div id="page2" class="content">

</div>               
<div id="page3" class="content">

    </div>

<div id="page4" class="content">

</div>
<div id="page5" class="content">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, that seems to work, but when I click on a tab, it seems to remove the text (or make both the tab bg and text white).

Comment: Right, because when you click the link, it shows only the corresponding div, and hides the others.  Are you looking for more of an accordion slider for the divs?

Comment: No, but when I click on a tab, I want the tabs to switch colours. So the inactive tab always has the same CSS and when you click a tab to make one active, they switch colours.

Comment: you could accomplish that by setting a css class for the regular/inactive `<li>` and then appending the `li a:active{
background-color:red;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code of **script.js – Part 2 from line# 31 to line# 43** with the code below:

```
if(!element.data('cache'))
{
    var msg - $(element.data('page')).html()
    $('#contentHolder').html(msg);
    element.data('cache',msg);
}
else $('#contentHolder').html(element.data('cache'));
```

On a side note.. why not use the tabs provided by jQuery UI if including jQuery UI in your existing code is not a big deal.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll look into using Jquery UI maybe. So you use Tabs = { 'Films' : 'dev#fragment-1' } with the code you posted above?

Comment: Yes. Also I fixed a typo in the answer.